# TWTRTwitter sessionStore now returns TWTRAuthSession: so how does one access the userName property now?

Tags: ios, swift, twitterkit

With TwitterKit 3.3.0 in Swift `sharedInstance().sessionStore.session()` now returns a `TWTRAuthSession` rather than a `TWTRSession`, as before. Things change, that's fine, however [the documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/twitterkit/ios/advanced-setup) hasn't been updated to reflect this, and as such I no longer know how to access the `userName` property that the former `TWTRSession` object offered.

Comment: Me too. This is really weird, at runtiem it looks like it still returns the old TWTRSession type. But any cast etc fails. TwitterKit has some quality problems... I guess I have to roll back to the previous version after all...

Comment: And btw, if I print out the `[Any]` array, it actually still holds the usernames and session cookies: ISSUE1084 sessions as [Any]: [<TWTRSession> mynameblbla - 832523035788173312]

Comment: @Jonny I like the idea of "runtiem". It sounds like some Vietnamese dish made of leftovers.

Comment: Culinary issues aside, the username data still exists in the back, but somehow the Vietnamese has managed to hide it from us.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with perform(_:)

Hope below will help those who face this.

```
let username = session.perform(#selector(getter: TWTRSession.userName))?.takeRetainedValue() as? String
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer @taka, I am so far away from this project now that I will be unable to verify your answer or not